# Is it possible to use NServiceBus and Azure WITHOUT Azure Emulator?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, nservicebus

I use this code:

```
        bus = bus ?? Configure.With()
            .DefaultBuilder()
            .AzureDiagnosticsLogger()
            .UseTransport<AzureStorageQueue>()
            .PurgeOnStartup(true)
            .UnicastBus()
            .CreateBus()
            .Start(() => Configure.Instance.ForInstallationOn<Windows>().Install());
```

And emulator settings are:
ServiceConfiguration azure file contains these settings:

```
  <Setting name="AzureQueueConfig.ConnectionString" value="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" />
  <Setting name="AzureQueueConfig.QueueName" value="webinputqueue" />
  <Setting name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig.ErrorQueue" value="errorqueue" />
  <Setting name="TransportConfig.MaximumConcurrencyLevel" value="1" />
  <Setting name="TransportConfig.MaxRetries" value="5" />
```

It works perfectly but it works ONLY with emulator. Everyone knows how the emulator is slow. So I am trying to find a way to run this NServiceBus with azure queues but without amulator. I tried to add the settings above to the web.config but it didn't help and shows the error:

```
Not running in a hosted service or the Development Fabric.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's perfectly possible to run outside of the emulator.

Just add in the correct configsection

```
<configSections>
     <section name="AzureQueueConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.AzureQueueConfig, NServiceBus.Azure" />
     <section name="TransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.TransportConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
      <section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
<configSections>
```

And put your config settings in corresponding config nodes

```
<AzureQueueConfig ConnectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true" QueueName="webinputqueue" />
<MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="errorqueue" />
<TransportConfig MaximumConcurrencyLevel="1" MaxRetries="5" />
```

This should do it, except for the AzureDiagnosticsLogger... You better replace that with another logger as the diagnostics service is obvioysly not available outside the roleenvironment